# JavaScript jQuery mobile after swipe event select is not updated / refreshed; css bug

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I have a problem with the update of a select-box

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <title>TimeControl</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" /> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

   </script>
</head>
<body>
      <select id="id1Auswahl4" name="auswahl4">
         <option value="null"
            selected="selected">...</option>
         <option value="1">abc</option>
         <option value="2">def</option>
      </select>
<script>
     document.getElementById("id1Auswahl4").selectedIndex=1;
     $("#id1Auswahl4").bind("swipe",
        function(event) {
              document.getElementById("id1Auswahl4").selectedIndex=2;
         });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

After doing a swipe-event on the mobile phone the value changed but will not be displayed in the select-box.

The error disappear when I take the jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css out.

Any ideas?

Best,
Chitarup

Comment: Try `.on()` instead of `.bind()`.

Comment: `$("#id1Auswahl4").selectmenu("refresh");`

Comment: No, doesn't help, but  `.change()` makes the job:         function(event) {
    document.getElementById("id1Auswahl4").selectedIndex=2;
    $("#id1Auswahl4").change();
    });`